# Performance issue in Scala code - O(nlgn) faster than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

I am just getting started with scala. I am trying to learn it by solving easy problems on leetcode. Here's my first (successful) attempt at [LC #977](https://leetcode.com/problems/squares-of-a-sorted-array/):

```scala
def sortedSquares(A: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    A.map(math.abs).map(x => x * x).sorted
}
```

Because of the sorting, I expected this to run `O(NlgN)` time, `N` being the size of the input array. But I know that there is a two-pointers solution to this problem which has a run-time complexity of `O(N)`. So I went ahead and implemented that in my noob Scala:

```scala
def sortedSquaresHelper(A: Array[Int], result: Vector[Int], left: Int, right: Int): Array[Int] = {
    if (left < 0 && right >= A.size) {
        result.toArray
    } else if (left < 0) {
        sortedSquaresHelper(A, result :+ A(right) * A(right), left, right + 1)
    } else if (right >= A.size) {
        sortedSquaresHelper(A, result :+ A(left) * A(left), left - 1, right)
    } else {
        if (math.abs(A(left)) < math.abs(A(right))) {
            sortedSquaresHelper(A, result :+ A(left) * A(left), left - 1, right)
        } else {
            sortedSquaresHelper(A, result :+ A(right) * A(right), left, right + 1)
        }
    }
}

def sortedSquares(A: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val min_idx = A.zipWithIndex.reduceLeft((x, y) => if (math.abs(x._1) < math.abs(y._1)) x else y)._2
    val result: Vector[Int] = Vector(A(min_idx) * A(min_idx))
    sortedSquaresHelper(A, result, min_idx - 1, min_idx + 1)
}
```

Turns out, the first version ran faster than the second one. Now I am quite confused about what I might have gotten wrong. Is there something about the recursion in second version that is causing high overhead?

I'd also like some suggestion about what is the idiomatic scala-way of writing the second solution? This is my first serious foray into functional programming, and I am struggling to write the function in a tail-recursive manner.

Comment: You can't sort in less than `O(n log n)`.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think that's relevant because the whole point of the second approach is to avoid sorting.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Maybe I didn't get the task then, shouldn't the array get sorted?

Comment: @Bergi The input array is also guaranteed to be sorted, which helps. As a simpler example, think of doubling instead of squaring; then just `input.map(_ * 2)` will produce sorted output from sorted input.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Ah, thanks, that wasn't stated anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Bergi It's on the LeetCode problem page to which I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector`s are [significantly slower than `Array`s overall](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#vectors-are-ok). In particular

> `Vector` item-by-item construction is 5-15x slower than `List` or `mutable.Buffer` construction, and even 40x slower than pre-allocating an `Array` in the cases where that's possible.

With `map` and `sorted` length of array is known, so they can be preallocated.

As that page mentions, `Vector#:+` is really logarithmic, so you end up with `O(n log n)` in both cases. Even if you didn't, `O(n log n)` vs `O(n)` technically only says something about how performance changes when input grows indefinitely. It's mostly aligned with what's faster for small inputs as well, but only mostly.

> I'd also like some suggestion about what is the idiomatic scala-way of writing the second solution?

One way is to construct a `List` in the reverse order, and then reverse it at the end. Or use an `ArrayBuffer`: even though it's mutable, you can effectively ignore that because you don't keep a reference to the older state anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried both `List` and `ArrayBuffer` for accumulating the result, but in the end I got better run time using `Array`. I think you are right that the input size on LeetCode is not really large enough to show any difference between the two approaches.